# Modal Popup is not appear on the top of the overlay in Bootstrap3. How to solve this prob

Tags: wordpress, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

In Bootstrap3, I had been create and customize Modal popup in my website. It is working. But unfortunately it appear inside the popup overlay.

Before click the button,
[image]

After click the button,
[image]

This is happend. So i adjust `Z-index` also. But it isn't benefit. My code is bellow,

```css
.csk-landing-for-scl {
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  text-transform: none;
}

.modal-open .modal {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal-dialog {
  position: relative;
}

.modal-content {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong" class="btn csk-landing-for-scl">Request a quote</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      content...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my code. So what can i do for it?

Comment: Please provide working code.

Comment: make sure the modal code is at the end of the `<body>` tag

Comment: Share your code in running environment like fiddle

Comment: What happened if you add to modal-content a `z-index: 1000;`

Answer (score 0):

yes, z-index is solution.please provide z-index value more than your header z-index value.It will be definitely solved.